# Is this proof on the Sylow 5-subgroups of G 100% correct?

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, symmetric-groups, sylow-theory

Problem statement :

Let $G=S_5$ (it actually reads $|G|=S_5$ but this must be a misprint obviously). Using Sylow , how many 5-Sylow subgroups has G got? Is this consistent with the number of 5 cycles in G?

My proof:

we have $|G|=|S_5|=120=5\cdot 24$.

By Sylow's first theorem we now know that the order of the  $5$-Sylow subgroups is 5.

By Sylow's 3rd theorem we know that the number of $5$-Sylow n_5=6.$

if $n_5=1$ then we also know that $|N_G(P)|=|G|$ but then this would imply that the normaliser contains every element in $G$ But of course $S_n$ is non-abelian for $n \geq 3$ so this can't be true.

We conclude that that $n_5=6$. So there are 6 $5$-Sylow -subgroups each with order $5$. These are distinct because the intersection is itself a subgroup and by Lagrange's theorem the intersection is either $1$ or $5$ and so must be $1$. so they intersect only at the identity. so any $5$-Sylow subgroup has order $5$ and contains the identity and $4$ $5$-cycles. Overall this means there are $(6\times 4=)\:24$ $5$-cycles, the same as would be expected in $S_5.$

Comment: "... be expected in $S_4$"???

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: $S_5$ nonabelian doesn't mean it cannot contain a proper normal subgroup.

Comment: yes I had started to grow concerned over that bit being wrong after I'd posted it. is all the rest correct though ?

Comment: The rest is OK (athough I wouldn't call calculating the order of a Sylow $p$ the content of the first Sylow theorem).  To conclude $n_5=6$, look at the subgroup $A_5$ which is simple.